# python create temp file namedtemporaryfile and call subprocess on it

Tags: python, subprocess, temporary-files

I'm having trouble generating a temp file and executing it afterward.
My process seems simple:
  - create temp file with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile
  - write bash instruction to the file
  - start a subprocess to execute the created file

Here is the implementation:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os
import subprocess

scriptFile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
with open(scriptFile.name, 'w') as f:
  f.write("#!/bin/bash\n")
  f.write("echo test\n")
  os.chmod(scriptFile.name, 0777)

subprocess.check_call(scriptFile.name)
```

I get  `OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy` on subprocess check_call.
How should I use the temp file to be able to execute it ?

Comment: dumb me... I was expecting the `with` context to close the file for me, which is not the case.

Comment: ``NamedTemporaryFile`` already opens the file (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html), which is why I am surprised that the error did not occur on the context-manager. Furthermore, the ``delete=True`` argument deletes the file when you close the connection, which makes it a peculiar use to use it later in a subprocess.

Comment: From what I see: the temp file is deleted when program ends not when the file is closed. I'm not sure if it is the normal behavior or if I need to handle this case...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As jester112358 pointed, it only requires the file to be closed.
I was expecting the with context to do this for me :\

Here's a fix

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os
import subprocess

scriptFile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
with open(scriptFile.name, 'w') as f:
  f.write("#!/bin/bash\n")
  f.write("echo test\n")

os.chmod(scriptFile.name, 0777)
scriptFile.file.close()

subprocess.check_call(scriptFile.name)
```